# What is the right way to parse wiki-style markup in scala?

Tags: scala, parsing

I'm trying to parse a wiki markup, eg:

```
*bold text*, /italics/, [[www.example.com][Title]] etc,
```

to create

**bold text**, *italics*, [Title](http://www.example.com) etc,

and trying to find the best way to deal with this. I started off by converting my string to a list, and parsing recursively char by char, and this works fine for basic formatting, but I'm now trying to expand the supported syntax for paragraphs and tables, for which a single pass doesn't seem sufficient.

I've seen some stuff about Parsers and combinators, but I've not yet found a resource that explains how to get the formatted text back, especially not when it'll be nested as wiki markup has a tendency to be. Regex seems like it would be massively inefficient, and line by line parsing, then char by char seems like it would be worse to read than my already convoluted attempt. I realise its a bad question to ask "How do I do this?", but I'm out of ideas. Just a simple example would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**
Welp, this is the best I could do - decided that regexes were too awkward to start with and ended up with this...

```
private def parse(toGo: List[Char], past: List[Char], current: List[Char], matching: Option[Char]) : (String, String) = {
  // There has to be a better way to do this....
  (matching, toGo) match {
    // Match whole line logic first
    case (Some('$'), t) if t.startsWith(List(' ', ' ', ' ')) => {
      t.dropWhile(x => x == ' ') match {
        case ('*' :: t) => ("<li>" + parse(t, List(), List(), None)._1 + "</li>", "ul")  
        case ('#' :: t) => ("<li>" + parse(t, List(), List(), None)._1 + "</li>", "ol")
        case ('h' :: '1' :: t) => ("<h1>" + parse(t, List(), List(), None)._1 + "</h1>", "")
        case ('h' :: '2' :: t) => ("<h2>" + parse(t, List(), List(), None)._1 + "</h2>", "")
        case ('h' :: '3' :: t) => ("<h3>" + parse(t, List(), List(), None)._1 + "</h3>", "")
        case ('h' :: '4' :: t) => ("<h4>" + parse(t, List(), List(), None)._1 + "</h4>", "")
        case ('h' :: '5' :: t) => ("<h5>" + parse(t, List(), List(), None)._1 + "</h5>", "")
        case ('h' :: '6' :: t) => ("<h6>" + parse(t, List(), List(), None)._1 + "</h6>", "")
        case _ => parse(t, List(), List(), None)
      }
    }
    case (Some('$'), '|' :: t) => {
      val cols = t.foldLeft(List(List.empty[Char])) {
        (acc, i) =>
          if (i == '|') acc :+ List.empty
          else acc.init :+ (acc.last :+ i)
      }
      val parsedCols = for (s <- cols) yield {
        "<td>" + parse(s, List(), List(), None)._1 + "</td>"
      }
      ("<tr>" + parsedCols.mkString + "</tr>", "table")
    }
    case (Some('$'), _) => parse(toGo, List(), List(), None)
    case (Some(':'), ':' :: t) => {
      val foundArticle = Article.getArticleByName(current.reverse.mkString)
      val title = t.takeWhile(x => wikiTitle(x))
      val link:String = foundArticle.id match {
        case -1 => "<a href=\"edit/" + foundArticle.title + "\"> " + title.mkString + "</a>"
        case _ => "<a href=\"" + foundArticle.title + "\"> " + title.mkString + "</a>"
      }
    parse(t.dropWhile(x => wikiTitle(x)), link.toList.reverse ::: past, List(), None)
    }
    case (Some(':'), c :: t) if (wikiTitle.apply(c) == false) => {
      val foundArticle = Article.getArticleByName(current.reverse.mkString)
      val link:String = foundArticle.id match {
        case -1 => "<a href=\"edit/" + foundArticle.title + "\"> " + foundArticle.title + "</a>" + c
        case _ => "<a href=\"" + foundArticle.title + "\"> " + foundArticle.title + "</a>" + c
      }
      parse(t, link.toList.reverse ::: past, List(), None)
    }
    case (Some(x), y :: t) if (x == y) => {
      val inner = parse(current.reverse, List(), List(), None)._1
      // Sort out the wiki char mappings here
      val wrapped = x match {
        case '*' => "<span style=\"font-weight:bold;\">" + inner + "</span>"
        case '/' => "<span style=\"font-style:italic\">" + inner + "</span>"
        case '_' => "<span style=\"text-decoration:underline\">" + inner + "</span>"
        case '-' => "<span style=\"text-decoration:line-through\">" + inner + "</span>"
        case '~' => "<pre>" + current.reverse.mkString + "</pre>"
        case _ => inner
      }
      parse(t, wrapped.toList.reverse ::: past, List(), None)
    }
    case (Some(x), y :: t) => parse(t, past, y :: current, Some(x))
    case (Some(x), Nil) => parse(current.reverse, x :: past, List(), None)
    case (None, w :: t) if (wikiMarkup(w)) => parse(t, current ::: past, List(), Some(w))
    case (None, h :: t) => parse(t, past, h :: current, None)
    case (None, Nil) => ((past.reverse ::: current.reverse) mkString, "p")
  }
}

private def parsedStringBuilder(parsedInfo: Iterator[(String, String)]): String = {
  var last = ""
  (for (line <- parsedInfo) yield (
    (line, last) match {
      case ((s, tag), l) if tag == l && tag == "p" => last = tag; s + "<br/>"
      case ((s, tag), l) if tag == l => last = tag; s
      case ((s, tag), l) if tag == "" => last = tag; "</" + last + ">" + s
      case ((s, tag), l) if l == "" && tag == "p" => last = tag; "<" + tag + ">" + s + "<br/>"
      case ((s, tag), l) if l == "" => last = tag; "<" + tag + ">" + s
      case ((s, tag), l) if tag == "p" => last = tag; "</" + l + "><" + tag + ">" + s + "<br/>"
      case ((s, tag), l) => last = tag; "</" + l + "><" + tag + ">" + s
    }
  )).mkString
} 

def toHTML: String = {
  parsedStringBuilder(for (l <- content.lines) yield parse(l.toList, List(), List(), Some('$')))

}
```

May have cleaned some stuff up I wasn't meant to so it might not be entirely clear, but still - There has to be a neater way?

Comment: AFAIK the reference implementation is a bunch of regexes thrown in a kettle and stirred counterclockwise, and wiki markup is therefore not really amendable to the nice and composable parsing techniques based on formal language theory. But I may be wrong, and/or you may get by with a nicer subset of wiki syntax.

Comment: There are a [couple of](https://github.com/search?q=markdown&type=Repositories&ref=advsearch&l=Scala) markdown parsers already available for Scala. Or do you want to implement one from scratch or need different markup than markdown?